# Error in google sample app compilation instructions?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-play-services

I followed the following instructions to build the google play services sample app "type a number":

"
1. Start Eclipse

1. Import the Google Play Services library project (available for download through the SDK manager):

   1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
   2. Select `SDK/extras/google/google_play_services/google_play_services_lib` (where `SDK` stands for the path where you installed your Android SDK)
   3. Click **Finish**
2. Import `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` **as a library**

   1. Click **File | Import | Android | Existing Android Code into Workspace**
   2. Select the `eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils` project
   3. Click **Finish**
   4. Right-click on `BaseGameUtils`, then click **Properties**
   5. In the project properties window, click the **Android** section
   6. Check the **Is Library** checkbox
   7. Add a reference to the `google_play_services_lib` project (click **Remove** to remove any broken references, then click **Add** to add the correct one)
3. Import the desired sample from the `eclipse_compat` directory (Project | Import | Android | Existing Android Source)
4. Go into the project properties window for that project (right-click, **Properties**) and check that this project has a reference to the `BaseGameUtils` project.

Your project should now compile. However, don't run it yet, since you still need to adjust your game's IDs in order for the sample(s) to work. 
"

However, in eclipse the file "GameHelper.java" is flagged and contains the following error:
 "GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions cannot be resolved to a type"

Does anyone know where the error lay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code available here instead: https://gist.github.com/EmmanuelVinas/ef09a35bcc805ba6deb3

Just cut everything from the imports of GameHelper.java to the end of it and then paste the contents of that gist as a replacement.

The problem is apparently because the location of ApiOptions changed in the last update.